# iptables is blocking only some connections to port 80

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I'm running a Ubuntu 15.10 server with an nginx webserver on it. I've used the following iptables configuration to allow port 80 and port 443 connections:

```
*filter

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and reject traffic
# to localhost that does not originate from lo0.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Allow ping.
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections.
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 950 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere
# (the normal ports for web servers).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow mail
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow inbound traffic from established connections.
# This includes ICMP error returns.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Log what was incoming but denied (optional but useful).
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound.
-A INPUT -j REJECT

# Log any traffic which was sent to you
# for forwarding (optional but useful).
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7
```

As confirmed by `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  127.0.0.0/8          anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:950 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp state NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This works... generally. Some connections to port 80 are blocked anyway (`/var/log/kern.log`):

```
Apr 15 11:50:47 while kernel: [6038916.249973] iptables_INPUT_denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=04:01:a4:e4:4d:01:84:b5:9c:fa:10:30:08:00 SRC=82.101.237.77 ST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=2368 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51182 DPT=80 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Why is iptables doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example log entry is for a TCP packet with the reset flag asserted.

For TCP connections, Linux tends to use a "half-duplex" close sequence where either side of the session can initiate connection termination via a single 2 way FIN-ACK handshake (which puts the connection into the CLOSE_WAIT state), instead of a full 4 way FIN-ACK handshake.

It is likely, and very common, that your side thinks a previous TCP session has been closed and has forgotten about it. Then 82.101.237.77 tried to reset the connection, which ended up as "iptables_INPUT_denied".

Summary: There is nothing wrong.